# Querying in PostgreSQL database at a single-time with multiple queries in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I Have a PHP service which has 4 to 5 queries.

and, for retrieving data from each query it takes min of 40-50 sec.

ex:

```
$res1=($conn,"select * from table1" );

$res2=($conn,"select * from table2" );

$res3=($conn,"select * from table3" );

$res4=($conn,"select * from table4" );

$res5=($conn,"select * from table8" );
```

so it's taking the execution time of 3 to 4 minutes(i.e(40Sec)*5)..

is there any way that i can call all the queries and fetch all the data at the same time?..

So that the total time taken for querying can be reduced to 1 minute.

I tried surfing about this, I got pg_send_query , but I don't think this resolves my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for postgresql. It might work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php

Comment: It is PostgreSQL itself.